# Compile Ember CLI project assets to multiple JS files

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a project with a need for multiple JS files. Some use cases:

- IE-only polyfills I include with a conditional comment and don't want
  mobile devices to download
- Large files not included on a landing page that I want to lazy load

It appears that ember cli allows for multiple CSS files, but not multiple JS files:

```
venter code herear app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      js: {
        app: '/assets/app.js',
        ie: '/assets/ie.js'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Errors:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'
    at module.exports (/Users/<me>/Projects/<my-app>/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/index.js:15:30)
    at EmberApp.concatFiles (/Users/<me>/Projects/<my-app>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:261:10)
    at EmberApp.javascript (/Users/<me>/Projects/<my-app>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:864:16)
    at EmberApp.toArray (/Users/<me>/Projects/<my-app>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1159:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/Users/<me>/Projects/<my-app>/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1181:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<me>/Projects/<my-app>/Brocfile.js:35:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

There's nothing in the guides about multiple JS files other than vendor; is there something I'm missing or is this a missing feature?

Answer (score -1):

Edit `app/index.html` and add the paths for the scripts you want to load above the other the other scripts. It should look something like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="assets/polyfill.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/my-application.js"></script>
```

To serve the `polyfill.js` file for you can add the code to `public/assets/polyfill.js`. This will make the file available statically.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of having the project generating multiple JavaScript files via the Ember app.  It's easy to "include" any number and type of files, but that is not what the original question is about.